# Firma digital con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, firma-digital, certificado

Actualmente tengo un formulario bastante simple, con HTML+PHP+Javascript+Ajax. Básicamente, cuando el form está completo, exporto PDF y CSV.

No obstante, ahora mismo el formulario se está "firmando" con Canvas, y estaba pensando en una solución mediante certificado digital y firma electrónica, para que la lleve cuando exporte el PDF (utilizo jsPDF para ello).

No estoy muy puesto en esto y no se si sería viable. ¿Qué me podéis comentar?

Actualmente estaba viendo libsodium (Paragonie), pero no sé si me vale para éste propósito.

¿Sabéis si en general es posible y que haría falta?

Gracias.

Comment: agrega tu codigo

Comment: Tendría que poner miles de lineas. ¿Qué parte del código necesitas?

Comment: fijate si este hilo te da pistas https://stackoverflow.com/q/33216843/1423096

Comment: y para php hay algo por aquí https://stackoverflow.com/q/21096261/1423096

Comment: Le echo un ojo. Gracias @aloMalbarez